# Change status of new port to be opend by code

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

I use the following code which working OK to provide available port

```
portscanner.findAPortNotInUseAsync(55001, 65000, 'localhost').
then(function (port) {
        ...
```

In real time the application is taking available port which change the status of the port to **open**, How can I simulate and changes the port status to open **by code** ?

I need it for internal test...

when I try the suggestion of Amina I got in error param the status of open
[image]

This is a screen shot from webstrom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `findAPortNotInUseAsync` use internally the function `checkPortStatus` that defined here: https://github.com/baalexander/node-portscanner/blob/master/lib/portscanner.js#L93

You can fork this project, and add exception to ports you want to set as open.
For example:

in the module portscanner.js file:

```
portscanner.manualOpenPort={}
portscanner.setPortToOpen=function(port){
  portscanner.manualOpenPort[port]=true
}
```

In you program:

```
portscanner.setPortToOpen(5050)
```

Now you need to add this line to the original `checkPortStatus` function:

```
portscanner.checkPortStatus = function(port, options, callback) {
  if (portscanner.manualOpenPort[port]) {
        callback(null,'open');
        return
  }
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried it and when I didnt do the setPortToOpen I got error  :TypeError: Cannot read property '55001' of undefined , where should I put the code of portscanner.manualOpenPort={} ... i've this module already (under node_modules) and I've folder lib with just one file potscanner.js...

Comment: In the portscanner.js

Comment: I've tried it now and it seems that when I use the portscanner.checkPortStatus I got open in the error,why ?  portscanner.checkPortStatus(port, host, function (error, status)

Comment: I mean the open value I got in the paramter of the function and not in the status param